# factorial function with custom numbers doesn't work

Tags: c++, class, math, friend, factorial

recently I've been working on a library to handle very large numbers with thousands of digits.
I have now worked on a factorial function for these things as I just set up multiplication.

```
largeNum factorial(largeNum& input) {
    if (input > one) return (input * factorial(--input));
    else return one;
}
```

"one" is a largeNum defined to have a value of"one" with a "+" sign since I haven't yet implemented integer conversion.

Factorial is a friend function of the largeNum class. I do not get any syntax errors, it has to be logical.

The prefix -- operator is properly overloaded and also tested.

So are multiplication and the ">" operator.

- Entering 5 returns 24 which is 4!
- Entering 6 returns 120 which is 5!. 
  And so on.

Maybe I'm just being plain blind as I'm a little sleep deprived but I need some help here. 
Cheers.

Comment: You are making assumptions about evaluation order, which results in undefined behaviour. I suggest changing `--input` to `input - 1`.

Comment: So here's the fun part. I tried that before and changing it to "input-one" results in me getting a negative power of 3 if input is even and a positive power of 3 if input isn't in 2 steps intervals.

Comment: So maybe your `operator-` is not properly defined?

Comment: `factorial` should probably take parameter as const reference instead of no const reference.

Comment: Note also that any decent compiler should have warned you about the UB, e.g. clang gives: `warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'input' [-Wunsequenced]`. You do have compiler warnings enabled, I hope ?

Comment: @Rogus the minus operator is very easy to implement and thus also very stable. All it does is return a value equal to the input, with a switched sign. Just ran some tests with it. the operator- works perfectly fine.

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve] and/or [learning how to use your debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) ?

Comment: "the minus operator is very easy to implement..." I think you are talking about the unary `-` which isnt really relevant here

Comment: how does you binary `-` look like ?

Comment: Why on Earth should the factorial function need access to internals of your number class? Put differently: why is it a friend at all?

Comment: btw "I do not get any syntax errors, it has to be logical." is a very dangerous misconception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question: the "unexpected" results, i.e. "entering 5 gives 4!, not 5!", has to do with undefined behaviour introduced by the following line of code:

```
input * factorial(--input)
```

Note that the order of evaluation of operators in C++ is mostly undefined (cf., for example, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)). So it may happen that `factorial(--input)` is evaluated before it's result is multiplied by the (in the meanwhile changed?) value of `input`. In conjunction with side effects, where an operation alters the same (or an other) object, this usually results in undefined behaviour when the same (or the other) object is used in the same expression without having a sequence point in between. Just as operation `n = ++i + i;` is UB (cf. [evaluation order / undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)).

Hence, this code may sometimes behave as you expect, but may also behave completely different.

So if `--input` has side effects on the contents of `input` (as we may asume), then your code has to be rewritten to

```
input * factorial(input-one)
```

where `(input - one)` must not alter `input` in any way (and has to be implemented such that it gives the correct result, of course).